# Deduce PMF $f(x)$ from joint PMF $f(n,x)=e^{-\lambda}\frac{(\lambda p)^{x}(\lambda q)^{n-x}}{x!\left(n-x\right)!}$

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

given the joint probability function
$$f(n,x) = e^{-\lambda}\frac{(\lambda p)^{x}(\lambda q)^{n-x}}{x!\left(n-x\right)!}$$

How do I make this in a form that I can sum over all n, to find f(x)?

I know it has got to do something with playing with (n-x)
and I know sum over all n of $t^n/n!$ is $e^t$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably your joint probability function comes from choosing $N \sim \operatorname{Poisson}(\lambda)$ and then $(X \mid N) \sim \operatorname{Binomial}(N, p)$. So, $X \le N$, and your sum should be over all $n$ such that $n \ge x$.

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=x}^\infty f(n,x)
&= e^{-\lambda} \frac{(\lambda p)^x}{x!} \sum_{n=x}^\infty \frac{(\lambda q)^{n-x}}{(n-x)!}
\\
&= e^{-\lambda} \frac{(\lambda p)^x}{x!} e^{\lambda q}
\\
&= e^{-p\lambda} \frac{(\lambda p)^x}{x!}.
\end{align}

Comment: You're a psychic (y)

Answer (score 2):

This is already in the valid form: 
$$
\sum_{n\geq x}e^{-\lambda}\frac{(\lambda p)^{x}(\lambda q)^{n-x}}{x!\left(n-x\right)!}=e^{-\lambda}\frac{(\lambda p)^{x}}{x!} \sum_{n\geq x}\frac{(\lambda q)^{n-x}}{\left(n-x\right)!}=e^{-\lambda}\frac{(\lambda p)^{x}}{x!}  e^{\lambda q}=e^{-\lambda p}\frac{(\lambda p)^{x}}{x!}. 
$$